# Centos 6.3 can't resolve hostname of network drive while others can

Tags: networking, centos, samba

I have a network drive (external network) being used as media storage for a media server running on my router. I'm trying to switch the media server to my Centos 6.3 machine so I can take advantage of `ffmpeg` and more (unrelated)..

All I'm wondering here is why my Centos server can't resolve the host name for the drive while my laptop running Ubuntu can on the same network. Ubuntu can ping it by host name and receive a response. Though I know Ubuntu has a GUI and I can click on "network" in the file system and find it there `smb://ballzdeep` it says is the location of the drive. Centos is sans GUI. I can't figure out why it doesn't find it and have been searching for a way to discover network hosts but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you should add your network's gateway address as a "nameserver" to the file

> /etc/resolv.conf

and see if it works. Ubuntu sometimes automatically do that, but I'm not sure if CentOS does it.

Comment: nice. i had edited my resolv.conf and put in my isp's dns.. changed it to my router and it pinged.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you can ping the host using the ip address to ensure that you have connectivity.

The most straightforward option to resolve this issue would be adding the following line to your `/etc/hosts` file.

> 192.168.1.1  hostname

Replace the IP address and hostname with values appropriate to your situation. This will allow your machine to resolve the hostname properly.

However, there might be some samba-specific configurations you have to do to share files that I can't recall off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

Check `/etc/resolv.conf` and add the line:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

In case it is not already added. Then restart the BIND service by:

```
$> service named restart
```

Then try pinging:

```
$> ping 8.8.8.8
$> ping google.com
```